# Multiplication of a matrix with a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find a matrix which should be an invertable matrix. however I keep getting that it's a matrix full of zeros, which of course is not invertible. So it seems something is not right in my answer.

For example, in order to find the first column of Q, I need to solve this:

Note- the columns of Q are eigenvectors..

[image]

Now this, if I'm not mistaken, should give me:

$$-10.225x_1 + 7.2x_2 = 0 $$
and
$$7.2x_1 - 5.055x_2 = 0$$

I keep getting $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = 0$. And the same goes when I try to find the second column of matrix Q.

I wanted to ask the following questions:

Am I doing this right? What is the echelon form? is it necessary I use it here to get the correct answer? or is it just a way to simplify the metrices multiplication?

Thank you.

##### EDIT -

So I underdtand now what is the echelon form. It won't make any difference I'll get the same answer.

Comment: Where are those values coming from? (Namely, $-10.255, 7.2, -5.055$.) The reason I ask is that you can "almost" solve those, with the near-solution $x_1 = t, x_2 = 1.4243 t$; the values are only a little bit off. So if they came from something that might have had some round-off error, maybe that explains it.

Comment: @BrianTung After I got the eigenvalues from $det(C - \lambda I) = 0$.. I got those numbers from $(C - \lambda I)x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this matrix *is* invertible, which means that the only solution of $Ax = 0$ is that $x=0$.

In more detail, this is a property of invertible matrices - for any $b$ the equation $Ax = b$ has a unique solution $x$. Since $A0 = 0$, the only solution of $Ax = 0$ is $x=0$.

If you want to find some *other* matrix $Q$ that contains the eigenvectors of $A$, the typical way is to write out the polynomial equation $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$, solve for $\lambda$, and then find solutions of $(A-\lambda I)x = 0$. Since $(A-\lambda I)$ is non-invertible, it will have non-zero solutions.

Comment: The thing is, I started with some symmetric $2x2$ matrix. I did exactly this, first I found the eignevalues using $det(C-\lambda * I)x = 0$, (I called the symmetric matrix $C$). I got the value of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then I wanted to find the corresponding eigenvectors which I will use as the columns of matrix Q, using $(C - \lambda_1 * I)x = 0$ and another equation with $\lambda_2$, and one of those two equations is the picture I added. Both times I get $x_1$ and $x_2$ equal to zero which means $Q$ is a matrix full of zeros... but this should not be the case...

Comment: Then you made a mistake in finding $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Comment: I've been checking my calculations over and over again, I can't seem to find the probelm. My original $C$ matrix is (5.6 7.2) in the first row, and (7.2 10.8) in the second row. I did exactly what I described above.. so does this mean my approach is correct?

Comment: The eigenvalues of that matrix are $\frac{1}{5}(41 \pm \sqrt{1465})$, and the corresponding $C -\lambda I$ will be pretty ugly, they will involve non-terminating decimals, you are rounding which is leading the result being non-singular. E.g. $\lambda_1$ is *about* 15.855, but "about" isn't good enough here, it needs to be exact.

Comment: In other words, stick with the fractions/roots as you solve for the eigenvectors

Comment: For larger matrices, you wouldn't have the luxury of "exact" solutions, as that would involve finding the roots of polynomials of high degree.  Instead, use a good numerical approximation (not just $3$ decimals, as many as your calculator will give you) and leave out one of the columns of $A - \lambda I$ when solving.